# No matching constructor found on class Actors.FileObserverActor for arguments

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka, actor

I am trying to implement websocket using akka actors in play frmework.

HomeController.scala

```
  def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => FileObserverActor.props(out))
  }
```

Actors/FileUploaderActor.scala

```
class FileUploaderActor extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {

    case UploadFile(billerId, filename, subCategory, count, dueDate) =>

      val fileOberverActor = ActorSystem().actorOf(Props[FileObserverActor])
      val billerData = BillerFileUploadMetaData(billerId,filename,count,"ACTIVE",
        new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime),subCategory,dueDate)
      val sparkSession = SparkContextHelper.sparkSession;
      import sparkSession.implicits._
      val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(billerData))
      val df = rdd.toDF()
      df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("keyspace" -> "billerplatform_schema", "table" -> "biller_file_uploads")).mode(SaveMode.Append).save
      fileOberverActor ! FileUploaded(filename, count)
  }
}
```

Actors/FileObserverActor.scala

```
class FileObserverActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case FileUploaded(fileName, totalRecords) =>
      out ! ("Got the file " + fileName)
  }

}

object FileObserverActor{
  def props(out: ActorRef)  = Props(new FileObserverActor(out))
}
```

Getting trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class Actors.FileObserverActor for arguments []
    at akka.util.Reflect$.error$1(Reflect.scala:81)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.findConstructor(Reflect.scala:105)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.<init>(IndirectActorProducer.scala:103)
    at akka.actor.IndirectActorProducer$.apply(IndirectActorProducer.scala:60)
    at akka.actor.Props.producer(Props.scala:131)
    at akka.actor.Props.<init>(Props.scala:144)
    at akka.actor.Props$.apply(Props.scala:86)
    at Actors.FileUploaderActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FileUploaderActor.scala:15)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:497)
    at Actors.FileUploaderActor.aroundReceive(FileUploaderActor.scala:10)
```

Is this a problem with creating an actor instance in FileUploaderActor? Can you help me to debug this issue.

Edit:
 I have created a companion object for "FileObserverActor" because its needed to establish a connection between controller and FileObserverActor through websocket,

```
def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => FileObserverActor.props(out))
  }
```

Now i also want to send message to "FileObserverActor" from "FileUploadActor", but i couldnt create a instance from "FileUploadActor" since the "FileObserverActor" is parameterised with "out:ActorRef" for websocket connection. Now how can i send a message to "FileObserverActor" from "FileUploadActor" ?

Comment: My best guess is that your FileObserverActor is not a top level class (the stacktrace says it's Actors.FileObserverActor) . Have you tried making it a public class?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia Sorry for the delayed reply. Both "FileObserverActor" and "FileUploaderActor" in a same package inside "Actors". So it shouldnt be a problem here right?.

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing Java and Scala together (been playing with both at the same time recently) and mixed up constructor visibility rules. Disregard the comment,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message points out it is expecting a no-argument constructor to `FileObserverActor` but it's not found. Given you need the `out: ActorRef` while creating `FileObserverActor`, consider passing a reference when you create it.

The offending line is on `Actors/FileUploaderActor.scala`

`val fileOberverActor = ActorSystem().actorOf(Props[FileObserverActor])`

You might want to change it to something like

`val fileOberverActor = ActorSystem().actorOf(FileObserverActor.props(outActorRef))`

For more information checkout the official documentation on [Props](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/actors.html#props) in Akka.

Comment: It's as @ashwanthkumar explained. Also, please (!) don't just write `ActorSystem()` in-line like that, it is supposed to host all the actors, so there's supposed to be one system per app. Here you create one system per message your actor is getting, this is a terrible idea and will lead to out of memory errors. Please read the getting started guide and basic docs on actors http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/guide/index.html